# if structure not working for NSDate validation

Tags: iphone, if-statement, nsdate

This is my code for checking if two `NSDate` objects have a values, the problem though is this structure is not working, I tried changing the `if` statements to for example `oldDate == nil`, but that also doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
    if (!oldDate && !newDate) {
        NSLog(@"oldDate & newDate are empty");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"oldDate & newDate have values");
    }

    if (!oldDate) {
        NSLog(@"oldDate is empty but newDate has a value");
    }
    else if (!newDate) {
        NSLog(@"newDate is empty but oldDate has a value");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two if/else blocks which get executed. But you want to have only one:

```
if (!oldDate && !newDate) {
    NSLog(@"oldDate & newDate are empty");
} else if (!oldDate) {
    NSLog(@"oldDate is empty but newDate has a value");
} else if (!newDate) {
    NSLog(@"newDate is empty but oldDate has a value");
} else {
    NSLog(@"oldDate & newDate have values");
}
```